# Create secure token in nodejs

Tags: node.js, security, cryptography, token, aes

I have a json with the date:

```
{
  password: 'mySecretPwd',
  validUntil: dayjs().add(1, 'hour').toDate(),
  userId: '29038492132'
}
```

Now I want to create something like a magic link (myUrl/). When the person is clicking on the link it has to open a webpage and the user has to write their password into a textfield. After submit it sends a request with the user input and the token from the link. The server then checks whether the input is equal to the user input in the token and validate the user or not.

Now my question is how to achieve that. My code looks like that:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

const algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr'
const secretKey = process.env.JWT_TEST_RESULT_SECRET

export const encrypt = (text) => {
  const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16)

  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, secretKey, iv)

  const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(text), cipher.final()])

  return {
    iv: iv.toString('hex'),
    content: encrypted.toString('hex')
  }
}
```

Because I need the iv for decoding, I would create the link like that: `myUrl/<content>_<iv>`

Is that a good and secure approach or not?

I hope you have some input.
THANKS for that

Comment: Are you planning to send `password` without encrypting?

Comment: No, I would make a string from the json and decrypt it like I showed in the encrypt function

Comment: It would be wrong to ignore Oauth or OpenId.
Why not just replicate their success? They verify the token by salt!
<header>.<payload>.<sait>

please do not store passwords and personal data in the token!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to implement 2fa into your project.

for 2fa authentication you would reset your user's password whenever they try to log in then send them a token as a response and save it in your project memory (in a variable or your state management).

for achieving it this way (not storing the token) it's better if you mail them after they ask to login, (you can use [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com) for that) a link they can click on and insert their password and of course along with their new password as well (I suggest you consider either only using a token with a static password or only sending them a password). like :

hi dear user, your new password is: NEW_PASSWORD, insert your password in the link below:
YOUR_FRONT_END.com/insert-password/?token=NEW_TOKEN&username=USERNAME (I suggest you put an expiration time of 2 min for the token)

in the front end we are looking for the token and the username in the query in [nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org) for example you can access the items in the query by writing this.$route.query.YOUR_DESIRED_ITEM_IN_QUERY.

if we got our desired item in the query we ask the user to insert their password, else we redirect them to the login page.

after they insert the password we send the username, password & token to the backend to validate them.

for validating password & hashing it:

I would consider using [bycrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs). since it is easy to use and you want to expire your password every 1 hour (which I recommend for 2 min). there is no need for something more complex.

but if you want to have a static password (and you want it to be as secure as it gets) for your users that won't change over time unless the users themselves update it, I suggest you don't store the password(even the hashed version of it) in the database.

for achieving that you must hash unchangeable data from the user (like the id) with your password as the key and store that hashed data in the database, this way even if the hashed data you've stored gets decrypted the attacker won't have access to the password, instead they would get the id.

FIRST STEP: convert your password to base 32. (you are going to use your password as your key latter on),

```
function convertPassword (secretKey, password) {
    
        if(!password.length || password.length > 32){
            return false;
        }
    
        if(secretKey.length !== 32) {
            return false;
        }
    
        return`${secretKey.split('').splice(password.length).join('')}${password}`;
        
    }
```

STEP 2: encryption

```
import {randomBytes, createCipheriv} from "crypto";    
function encrypt (textToEncrypt, secretKey) {
    
        if(secretKey.length !== 32){
            return false
        }
    
        const cipher = createCipheriv('aes-256-ctr', secretKey, randomBytes);
    
        const encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(textToEncrypt), cipher.final()]);
    
        return  `${randomBytes.toString('hex')}:${encrypted.toString('hex')}`
    
    }
```

in this step you pass user id as the "textToEncrypt" & converted password as
"secretKey".

and finally the LAST STEP: decryption

```
import {createDecipheriv} from "crypto";
    function decrypt (encryptedText, secretKey, id) => {
        
        if(secretKey.length !== 32){
            return false
        }

        const splicedHash = encryptedText.split(':')
    
        const hashIv = splicedHash[0]
        const hashContent = splicedHash[1]
    
        const decipher = createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', secretKey, Buffer.from(hashIv, 'hex'));
    
        const decrypted = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(hashContent, 'hex')), decipher.final()]);
    
        const result = decrypted.toString();
        
        return result === id;
    }
```

encryptedText is the text you've stored into your database, secretKey is the password that user has inserted and you've ran through your convert password function and id is the user id that you have used to encrypt.
this function returns true if the password is valid and false if its not.

PS: if your project doesn't require THAT much security i'd still suggest you use bycrypt

Comment: No its for downloading their photos from a shooting. They can download it for 3 days.
The idea is that they are getting the mail with the link, click on it and just insert their birthday. One secret is the birthday (but a bad one) and another stronger one is the link itself, because it is encrypted.

Comment: I see where you're going. you want to deny public access to your server's media and let people access their media only for a limited time, right? 
unfortunately, that is not possible. actually, it is not scalable and achievable.

you can handle the validation you mentioned in a route and in some circumstances return a file you have stored into your server.

PS: you can use the functions I've posted in the answer above for encryption & decryption these guys work ;)

Comment: the main problem is where you got for example 100GB of data, for storing that you are going to want to store your files in Object Storage like AWS s3 buckets.
coz A: you probably don't want to store that amount of data in your server because of the high prices of servers and B: you DONT want your backend to deal with transferring that amount of data in a single request.

if this was possible Hollywood would come up with something for their movies.